# Clipboard Support in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, clipboard

I'm looking at developing a Silverlight application that displays a lot of information in a DataGrid.

I want to *somehow* give the users the ability to copy this into Excel via the clipboard.

Is this even possible in Silverlight 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've figured out how to do it, but it's not exactly elegant.

First of all, I lifted the CopyClipboard function from [Jeff Wilcox's Blog](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/05/clipboard-access/).

Now I've written code to generate an HTML table from the grid, and put that into the clipboard.

```
    private void Clipboard_Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<TABLE>");
        foreach (object obj in myDataGrid.ItemsSource)
        {
            sb.Append("<TR>");
            foreach (DataGridColumn c in myDataGrid.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append("<TD>");
                FrameworkElement el = c.GetCellContent(obj);
                TextBlock tb = el as TextBlock;
                if (tb != null)
                {
                    string s = tb.Text;
                    sb.Append(System.Windows.Browser.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(tb.Text));
                }
                sb.Append("</TD>");
            }
            sb.Append("</TR>");
        }
        sb.Append("</TABLE>");
        Clipboard.SetText(sb.ToString()); 
    }
```

It's especially bad because it's calling

```
clipboardData.Invoke("setData", "text", text);
```

rather than

```
clipboardData.Invoke("setData", "text/html", text);
```

Because the second one throws a "System.InvalidOperation" exception. That means if you copy it into Word instead of Excel it isn't a table, it's a block of HTML.

But, yes, copying the datagrid contents to Excel via the clipboard is possible. Sort of.

Comment: The Flash hack is pretty wild, but thanks for linking to it.

I hope we add better clipboard support to a future release of Silverlight, it would be useful for advanced grids and other controls.

Answer (score 2):

No, this feature isn't available in SL3.

Please read (Links talk about version 2, but that hasn't changed ever since):

[Copy text to clipboard?](http://silverlight.net/forums/t/13024.aspx)

[Storing text in the clipboard using Silverlight 2](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2008/05/clipboard-access/)

Answer (score 2):

I really recommend using this solution using a hidden textbox:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manishdalal/archive/2008/11/12/cross-browser-copy-and-paste-in-datagrid-with-excel-support-part-1.aspx

I've used it to get copy and paste functionality from excel into a datagrid and it works very nicely.

HTH